# Saving Interactive Bokeh Chart

Tags: python-2.7, bokeh

I have created an interactive Bokeh chart with various widgets which allow manipulation of the data. I now want to understand what is the standard way of sharing such a plot or how do I save it for sharing.

The plot is created with the curdoc method and then output to the Bokeh server using session.show().

```
#create current visualization using plot p and widgets inputs
curdoc().add_root(HBox(inputs, p, width=1100))

#run the session
session = push_session(curdoc())
session.show() # open the document in a browser
session.loop_until_closed() # run forever
```

Answer (score 4):

Does the app trigger actual python code?

If not, you might consider reworking it as a non-server standalone document (using `CustomJS` callbacks, for instance). That would just generate a self-contained static HTML file that you could publish or send anywhere, and have it be immediately accessible.

If your app *does* rely on executing actual python code to do the work, then it needs to actually be *running somewhere* for users to interact with it. First off, I would suggest you make a real app that runs in the server, like the ones [in the demo app gallery](http://demo.bokehplots.com/) (see also [Use Case Scenarios](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#use-case-scenarios) in the User's Guide). A real server app, i.e. one you run like `bokeh serve myapp.py`, is definitely preferred over using `bokeh.client`, especially for "publishing" scenarios (it will also be simpler/less code and more performant). Then, distributing the app could mean a few things:

- You give them the script and they run `bokeh serve app.py` locally themselves
- You "deploy" the app by leaving it running on a server with a URL that is accessible to users who you want to be able to see it

Depending on how much compute the app does, and how many users you expect at a given time, the second option could be as simple as running `bokeh serve app.py` somewhere. But if there is heavy compute or you expect a lot of traffic, you may need more sophisticated "scale out" deployments behind a load balancer. More information is in [Deployment Scenarios](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#deployment-scenarios) in the User's Guide, and of course we are happy to help wth more extended discussions on the [public mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/?pli=1#!forum/bokeh). Finally, I should mention that in the near future, automated scalable publishing of Bokeh applications will be available as a feature on https://anaconda.org/

Comment: Yes the app triggers python code to continuously update the data based on widget selection, very similar setup to the Movies example shown in your link. I guess I am interested in understanding how to deploy such an app

Comment: the links I gave above have a good amount of information about different deployment scenarios. Beyond that I would suggest visiting the public mailing list, since it will probably be more of a discussion about the details of your particular scenario to provide help.